# Application crashed while Writing data to excel file in android

Tags: android, excel

I am writing an application that writes data into excel file in android...But my application crashes please help me where i did the mistake

Here's my MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.excel_file;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    Button writeExcelButton,readExcelButton;
    static String TAG = "ExelLog";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        writeExcelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        writeExcelButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        readExcelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        readExcelButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
        case R.id.button1:
            saveExcelFile(this,"myExcel.xls");
            break;
        case R.id.button2:  
            readExcelFile(this,"myExcel.xls");
            break;   
        }
    }

    private static boolean saveExcelFile(Context context, String fileName) { 

        // check if available and not read only 
        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) { 
            Log.e(TAG, "Storage not available or read only"); 
            return false; 
        } 

        boolean success = false; 

        //New Workbook
        Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

        Cell c = null;

        //Cell style for header row
        CellStyle cs = wb.createCellStyle();
        cs.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.LIME.index);
        cs.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);

        //New Sheet
        Sheet sheet1 = null;
        sheet1 = wb.createSheet("myOrder");

        // Generate column headings
        Row row = sheet1.createRow(0);

        c = row.createCell(0);
        c.setCellValue("Item Number");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(1);
        c.setCellValue("Quantity");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        c = row.createCell(2);
        c.setCellValue("Price");
        c.setCellStyle(cs);

        sheet1.setColumnWidth(0, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(1, (15 * 500));
        sheet1.setColumnWidth(2, (15 * 500));

        // Create a path where we will place our List of objects on external storage 
        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName); 
        FileOutputStream os = null; 

        try { 
            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            wb.write(os);
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file); 
            success = true; 
        } catch (IOException e) { 
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e); 
        } catch (Exception e) { 
            Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e); 
        } finally { 
            try { 
                if (null != os) 
                    os.close(); 
            } catch (Exception ex) { 
            } 
        } 
        return success; 
    } 

    private static void readExcelFile(Context context, String filename) { 

        if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) 
        { 
            Log.e(TAG, "Storage not available or read only"); 
            return; 
        } 

        try{
            // Creating Input Stream 
            File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), filename); 
            FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(file);

            // Create a POIFSFileSystem object 
            POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);

            // Create a workbook using the File System 
            HSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new HSSFWorkbook(myFileSystem);

            // Get the first sheet from workbook 
            HSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

            /** We now need something to iterate through the cells.**/
            Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();

            while(rowIter.hasNext()){
                HSSFRow myRow = (HSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                    HSSFCell myCell = (HSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Cell Value: " +  myCell.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(context, "cell Value: " + myCell.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }

        return;
    } 

    public static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() { 
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 

    public static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() { 
        String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState(); 
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) { 
            return true; 
        } 
        return false; 
    } 
}
```

This is my log cat:

```
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at com.example.excel_file.MainActivity.saveExcelFile(MainActivity.java:71)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at com.example.excel_file.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 02:29:39.550: E/AndroidRuntime(6111):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.excel_file"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have NoClassDefFoundError. I think, during compilation *org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook* class is present but it wasn't found in your device during runtime. Here you can read explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/34419/1555366